# Directions and Route in iPhone using Bing Map

Tags: iphone, bing-maps, driving-directions

Can we load a Bing Map in iPhone and show Route between source and destination points thourgh some waypoints.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the route-me project: [route-me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/)

This supports slippy map display of all kinds of maps (including Bing Maps) and also allows you to draw routes on top. However you need to make sure to have the right to use the maps in that way (make sure to check the license agreement with Bing Maps).

Answer (score 1):

- [Great Blog post with resources for iPhone <-> Virtual Earth Dev](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/blogs/maps/archive/2008/11/13/developing-virtual-earth-iphone-applications-with-objective-c.aspx)
- [Bing SDK for iPhone](http://ibing.codeplex.com/)